# boto3 eks client how to generate presigned url

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-eks

I'm trying to update a docker image within a deployment in EKS. I'm running a python code from a lambda function. However, I don't know how to use `generate_presigned_url()`. What should I pass as ClientMethod parameter???

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("eks")
url = client.generate_presigned_url()
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the clientMethods that you could perform in case of **EKS**.

```
'associate_encryption_config'
'associate_identity_provider_config'
'can_paginate'
'create_addon'
'create_cluster'
'create_fargate_profile'
'create_nodegroup'
'delete_addon'
'delete_cluster'
'delete_fargate_profile'
'delete_nodegroup'
'describe_addon'
'describe_addon_versions'
'describe_cluster'
'describe_fargate_profile'
'describe_identity_provider_config'
'describe_nodegroup'
'describe_update'
'disassociate_identity_provider_config'
'generate_presigned_url'
'get_paginator'
'get_waiter'
'list_addons'
'list_clusters'
'list_fargate_profiles'
'list_identity_provider_configs'
'list_nodegroups'
'list_tags_for_resource'
'list_updates'
'tag_resource'
'untag_resource'
'update_addon'
'update_cluster_config'
'update_cluster_version'
'update_nodegroup_config'
'update_nodegroup_version'
```

You can get more information about these method in the documentation here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#client

Comment: Hey @KnowledgeGainer thanks for answering, in this context `ClientMethod` is the first parameter name for the method `generate_presigned_url()` I would like to generate a pre-signed URL and I need to pass something to that method, but I don't know what

Comment: @juanp_1982 Does this function match your requirement ? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#EKS.Client.update_nodegroup_version

Comment: In this documentation:  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#client , the client method thats suits your requirement,  will come into the __ClientMethod__ of signed_url

Comment: Last 5 client methods might be useful otherwise, I don't see any other method performing update function.

Answer (score 0):

After over two weeks I suppose you've found your answer, anyway the *ClientMethod* mentioned (and, not really well explained on the boto3 docs) is just *one* of the methods you can use with the EKS client itself. I honestly think this is what KnowledgeGainer was trying to say by listing all the methods, basically you can just pick one. This would give you the presigned URL.

For example, here I'm using one method that isn't requiring any additional arguments, `list_clusters`:

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client("eks")
>>> client.generate_presigned_url("list_clusters")
'https://eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/clusters?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQKOXLHHBFT756PNG%2F20210528%2Feu-west-1%2Feks%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210528T014603Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d25dNCC17013ad9bc75c04b6e067105c23199c23cbadbbbeForExample'
```

If the method requires any additional arguments, you add those into `Params` as a dictionary:

```py
>>> method_params = {'name': <your_cluster_name>}
>>> client.generate_presigned_url('describe_cluster', Params=method_params)
```